# Confidence interval: "$v_2$ is at most $x$ larger than $v_1$, with a confidence of $95\%$"

Tags: confidence-interval

I have two unknown values $v_1$ and $v_2$ and two sets of measurements $S_1$ and $S_2$ of these values. The measurements can be assumed to have a normal distribution.

I would like to say something like *"$v_2$ is at most $x$ greater than $v_1$ with a confidence of 95%"*.

So, how small may $x$ be, in order to be 95% sure that that $v_2$ is greater than $v_1 + x$?

Comment: I don't see why this is off topic.  Looks like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I tagged it because stats questions tend to get better and more thorough answers on stats.SE...!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $S_1$ is normal, the [best guess you can have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) for the distribution is that $v_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ where $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_!$ are $S_1$'s sample mean and sample variance, respectively.

The difference $v=v_1-v_2$ is the difference of two independent normally distributed variables, and therefore $$v\sim N\left(\mu_1-\mu_2\ ,\ \sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}\right)$$
Then you simply use the inverse error function to find $x$ for which $P(v>x)<0.05$.

Comment: This is showing a lower limit for $v_1$, not anything about the difference $v_1-v_2$

Comment: Oops, didn't read well your question. But this is still simple. The distribution of the $v_1-v_2$ is Gaussian with mean $\mu_1-\mu_2$ and variance $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$. From this you can again calculate using the (inverse) error function.

Comment: Everyone is assuming independence? Where was that mentioned in the problem? If S1 and S2 are bivariate normal the difference will still be normal but the vaince would be σ$^2$1+σ$^2$2-2cov(S1,S2). @yohBS you either meant standard deviation or you should have left off the square root.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the section on estimation of parameters in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), you get estimates of the means $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and variances $s_1, s_2$.  The variance on the difference is the sum of the variances and you can use that and the difference of the means to evaluate $x$.